# FlatList performance warning issue when using the useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, react-native

I get a warning in my FlatList when using the useEffect hook to fetch data.

This is the complete component to reproduce the issue:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  SafeAreaView,
  Button
} from "react-native";

const Test = props => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=${page}&_limit=20`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        //console.log(res);
        setPeople(people => [...people, ...res]);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [page]);

  const loadMore = () => {
    setPage(page + 20);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={people}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Text>{item.id}</Text>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
        ListFooterComponent={
          loading ? (
            <ActivityIndicator />
          ) : (
            <Button title="Load More" onPress={loadMore} />
          )
        }
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

This is the warning I'm getting

> VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. Object {
>     "contentLength": 4418,
>     "dt": 705,
>     "prevDt": 669,
>   }

It basically tells me to use `PureComponent` or `shouldComponentUpdate`, though, but AFAIK both do not work with either a functional component or the `useEffect` hook, do they?

Although I did not notice a (huge) performance drop, I'm still wondering if there's a workaround to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

**Edit**: Using a PureComponent *does not* fix the issue:

Created PureComponentTest.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const PureComponentTest = props => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.id}</Text>
      <Text>{props.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default PureComponentTest;
```

And in my Component I updated `renderItem={renderItems}`:

```
  const renderItems = itemData => {
    return (
      <PureComponentTest
        id={itemData.item.id}
        title={itemData.item.title}
      />
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don’t see anything wrong with your component. It’s a very simple pure component. It may simply because the fetched data is too big. Try reduce the number of pages fetched each time. say 5 or 10 pages

Comment: The warning occurs if the list gets too long since I merge the results. I could do a pagination in my app but I consider infinite scrolling as the better UI experience.

Maybe this is only a false warning because useEffect does not use shouldComponentUpdate? It uses the dependency `[page]` though. I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the warning is for fetch into useEffect, so review the next documentation:

> Some rules to keep in mind about the useEffect hook:
>
> You cannot call a hook within a conditional; Hooks must be called in
>   the exact same order. Putting the useEffect inside of a conditional
>   could break that cycle; The function you pass the hook cannot be an
>   async function, because async functions implicitly return promises,
>   and a useEffect function either returns nothing or a cleanup function.

Consider use it:

```
fetch(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=${page}&_limit=20`)
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(res => {
        //console.log(res);
        setPeople(people => [...people, ...res]);
      })
 .catch(error=> console.error(error))
 .finally(() => setLoading(false));
```